# Custom logic events sending between components in React

Tags: reactjs, events, observer-pattern

I have some experience with react and I do use concepts of state, properties, context. What I am still struggling is how people deal when they need to have some kind of observer (or signal-slot, publisher-subscriber, etc.) concept that exist in every UI framework I have seen, and I do not see in react. Though I find it useful. E.g.

```
class Parent extend Component {
  onChange = null

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <A
          onChange={j, k, l => onChange(j, k, l)}
          />
        <B
          setOnChange={handler => { this.onChange = handler }}
          />
      </div>
      )
  }
}

class A extends Component {
   state = {
     j, k, l
   }

   render() {
     <SomeComponent value={this.state.k} onChange={v => this.onKChange} />
     <SomeComponent value={this.state.l} onChange={v => this.onLChange} />
     <SomeComponent value={this.state.j} onChange={v => this.onJChange} />
   }


   onKChange(k) {
     this.setState({k})
   }

   onLChange(l) {
     this.setState({l})
   }

   onJChange(j) {
     // do some specific logic on j, k, l values
     // and decide *if* need to fire an event
     if (doFire) {
       this.props.onChange(j, this.state.k, this.state.l)
     }
   }
}

class B extends Component {
  componentDidMound() {
    this.props.setOnChange(this.onChange.bind(this))
  }

  onChange(j, k, l) {
    // do some heavy work depending on j, k, l
  }
}
```

Why props are not use? I do not want to re-render `B` every time one or any of `j/k/l` is changed and have this specific logic that is in `onJChange` about `j/k/l` that decides if an action should be taken or not. How do you deal with this kind of situations? Do you have your observer utility library or there is something commonly used or do I approach this incorrectly?

Comment: you can use react-redux and wrap your component with a connect() function that provides you the possibility to read from your central application store. Your component will re-render automatically when your store is updated (e.g. an action is dispatched to the store that results in a change).

Comment: I had some experience with redux, I am not using it in the current project and try to avoid that it is seems to cumbersome and global, that many people find a concern as well. Can you think of any other more lightweight solution?

Comment: React create context maybe? I've not used it myself but it should be easier than redux. However I think once you understand redux you're set to make complex stateful applications.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#reactcreatecontext